# Schedule notification at the right time using javascript Date() in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, notifications

I am trying to schedule a notification based on a time i am getting from a server.
the problem is the notification shows but its not showing at the right time sometimes it display at the right time and sometimes it doesn't i am not sure why, i think the problem is with the time formatting the one i am getting from the server and the devices time. here an example time i am getting from the server : `2019-12-20T13:55:00.000` now i want to schedule a notification with this time i am doing something like this:

```
var notifDate = new Date("2019-12-20T13:55:00.000").getTime()
var currentDate = new Date().getTime()
var diff = notifDate - currentDate

Notification.schedule(diff)
```

now my questions is how can i ensure every notification is gonna display at the right time and maybe if i have to make the currentDate and notifDate the same format. i don't know much about how Date works. i know this question doesnt state much but anykind of suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What library is your `Notification.schedule` from?  Or is that your own code?

Comment: Also, is the timestamp string you have already in terms of the device's local time zone?  Or is it in UTC or some other time zone because it came from a server?

Comment: No its just kind of a pseudo code i am using react-native-push-notification library

Comment: I am not sure the time is coming from the server

Comment: Sorry, i also have these data related to the timestamp timezone=3 dst=U tz_time_zone=Africa/Addis_Ababa

Comment: Pseudocode is not useful in understanding the problem.  Please post actual code that reproduces the issue.  See [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center.

Comment: Yes but its not relevant the library is working as expected, i tried it with 10 secs 20 secs and it works perfect. The problem is with the timing

Comment: Are you using [`PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule`](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/master/README.md#scheduled-notifications)?  That takes a `Date` object for the time to run, not the calculated difference between now and then.

Comment: Yes i am using that...yes but i tried that before nothing shows at all...i guess the problem is with the device time formatting and the server date...is there a way i could format the server date with the current device formatting..for ex- if my device is using 24 hr formatting the server time should also be converted to 24hr

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean by that.  The timestamps you are showing are already in 24 hour format.  The only question is what time zone they are represented in.  Are they UTC based? Or are they based on `Africa/Addis_Ababa` that you gave?  (The best option really is to send a UTC based timestamp from the server.)